# Is "raster" is a specific format or a general term (regarding CUPS printing library)

Tags: graphics, cups, image, printing

I have seen related to the CUPS library, these two files:

- [OpenPrinting/cups-filters/blob/master/filter/imagetoraster.c](https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cups-filters/blob/master/filter/imagetoraster.c)
- [OpenPrinting/cups-filters/blob/master/cupsfilters/raster.c](https://github.com/OpenPrinting/cups-filters/blob/master/cupsfilters/raster.c)

I'm not sure what the `raster.c` does exactly yet, but `imagetoraster.c` essentially takes a PNG/JPEG/etc. and "converts it to raster format" it sounds like. I don't quite understand what this means exactly. Some printers are "PostScript printers", others are "Raster printers", but I am not sure if this term "raster" means that there is some sort of "Printer Raster Format" like PNG or JPG, or if it's just an array of pixels of some sort, or something else. It seems that the printers would have some sort of standard format, but calling it "raster" seems a bit misleading since raster is basically an arbitrary pixel representation of something (from my understanding).

Hoping one could clarify what exactly is meant by raster in this CUPS filter / printing library. I keep thinking it's actually a IANA mime-type of some sort, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Raster normally means that the image exists on a raster grid of pixels, i.e. that it is bitmapped and each pixel is addressable by an `x,y` coordinate. That is in contrast to Postscript and vector images where a line or rectangle would be described by its endpoints or vertices.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>**Preliminary Note:** What you quote is not the native CUPS API. It is part of the **OpenPrinting** project's library. OpenPrinting supplies and maintains a set of filters which can be integrated and docked into CUPS, mainly for Linux users, since Apple no longer supports this OS directly and instead handed over the respective CUPS code parts to the Linux Foundation...</sub>

---

In the context of CUPS and the two library source files you mentioned, "raster" is a specific raster format defined here (and it is actually registered with IANA as mime type `'application/vnd.cups-raster'`):

- https://www.cups.org/doc/spec-raster.html

So, this is neither TIFF, nor PNG, nor JPEG. CUPS-raster is an image format specific to CUPS, and developed to be used with CUPS.

This format takes an intermediary role for some types of print jobs when a conversion is required for a printable document format (like PostScript, PDF, TIFF, JPEG, PNG, Text, ...) to such a format which the printer can consume. *(If you buy a printer today, chances are around 95% that it can directly consume PDF -- so no real conversion is required!)*

However, if a printer is not PDF-enabled (as are older models, like many HP PCL-only devices), then you need to convert your printable format to the printer's liking. You can see the "intermediary" role of CUPS raster in the possible chains of file format conversions which CUPS may automatically set up for each print job:

```
  ## FILE FORMAT CONVERSIONS
  PDF -> CUPS-raster -> PCL6     # PCL6-consuming printer
  PDF -> CUPS-raster -> PCL3     # PCL3-consuming printer
  PDF -> CUPS-raster -> ESC/P    # EPSON's ESC/P consuming printer
```

To accomplish these conversions, CUPS employs a chain of "filters", which convert from one format to another. It constructs these chains automatically for each print job, depending an current need as signalled by print input and required (by the target printer) output:

```
  ## CUPS FILTERING CHAIN EXAMPLES
  (PDF input)        -> pdftoraster   -> rastertohp     # PCL6-consuming printer
  (PostScript input) -> gstoraster    -> rastertohp     # PCL3-consuming printer
  (TIFF input)       -> imagetoraster -> rastertoescpx  # EPSON's ESC/P consuming printer
  (PNG input)        -> imagetoraster -> rastertopwg    # any IPP-Everywhere printer
  (JPEG input)       -> imagetoraster -> rastertopdf    # any PDF-enabled printer
  (PDF input)        -> pdftoraster   -> rastertoqpdf   # some Samsung printers consuming SPLIX
```

You should poke around in the directory */usr/lib/cups/filter/* on Linux (or */usr/libexec/cups/filter/* on macOS) to see the list of all installed filters on your system. If you have access to both, Linux and macOS, you will see quite a few differences:

- **macOS:** for example, on macOS you'll see the *`cgpdftoraster`* filter which is proprietary to Apple and not released as Open Source and not available on Linux. (It is interfacing with Apple's *Core Graphic* Library, which isn't used on Linux anyways.) This converts to the CUPS raster format.

  Then there are (at least) two more filters which take over the produced CUPS raster and convert it further: `rastertopwg` and `rastertourf`:

  - URF is a (proprietary to Apple) raster format, which all AirPrint-enabled and -certified printers must support.
  - PWG is a raster format specified by the [*Printer Working Group* (PWG)](https://www.pwg.org/). It is very similar to URF, and every [*IPP Everywhere*](https://www.pwg.org/ipp/everywhere.html)-certified printer is required to support it.

  There may be additional *rastertoXYZ* filters on your system, if you have installed any vendor's printer driver.
- **Linux:** for example, on Linux (with OpenPrinting's *`cups-filters`* package installed) you will see the *`{pdf,image,gs}toraster`* which also convert to the CUPS raster format.

  The two filters *`rasterto{pdf,pwg}`* convert CUPS raster to PDF and to PWG raster.

  Again: there may be additional *rastertoXYZ* filters on your system, if you have installed any vendor's proprietary printer driver, or if you have installed additional printer driver packages such as HPLIP, Gutenprint, printer-driver-foo2zjs, printer-driver-splix or printer-driver-brlaser (package names are for Debian).

---

To see which specific input file format mime type can be converted by which filter to which specific output mime type, you should look into and read all your system's */usr/share/cups/mime/*.convs* files.

---

A "raster printer" in CUPS' parlance is any printer which does not consume PDF or PostScript. *(Strictly speaking, on the market there are also printers which can consume Microsoft's XPS/OXPS printing format which is also vector based. But these are not supported by CUPS, neither on macOS nor on Linux. Vendors provide drivers only for Windows.)*

Comment: While the answert is perfect, I would label the "chances are around 95% that it can directly consume PDF" part as overly optimistic. Actually, moving towards WiFi Direct and similar printers, there's less and less chance, especially in the lower price range. Unfortunately.